# C# timer with resuming and immediate start

Tags: c#, timer

I want to implement a timer with the following property: It has a long interval (for example 30 minutes) and if I stop it at the time for example 10 minutes and then resume it, timing will continue  immediately from that point. Also I want my timer to start  immediately, not 30 minutes after enabling. I'm making a console game and I need this. How could I do that please ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow please read our [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections.

Comment: Have you looked at the various Timer classes available in the .Net framework?

Comment: [One search result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I know System.Timers and System.Threading.Timers, but I can't implement both of the function I want.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard, simply store the duration left (initially the whole duration) in a variable.

When you start your timer, spawn a `Timer` class with the duration left. When you stop your timer, kill the `Timer` and subtract the elapsed time from the duration left.  If this thing ever triggers either stop everything (done) or reset it from the beginning (duration left is the full duration again).

Comment: do you have any suggestions how to evaluate the elapsed time if timer is paused between ticks?

Comment: Sure, you store the `DateTime` when you start the timer, and when you need the elapsed time you can calculate the difference between now and then. Or use the `Stopwatch` class. Keep in mind he's talking about *thirty minute* intervals, a few milliseconds here and there won't be that big a deal, especially for a game.

Comment: i think, DateTime.Now is not good choice, because it is so easy to change local machine time. but if i create a new Stopwatch and will reset it on each timer tick, it should represent correct elapsed time, right?

Comment: On each tick *and on each pause*. "Pausing" this timer actually destroys a system timer and recreates it again when it "resumes", but with a lower interval. The time tracking mechanism in your app has to do the same. It's up to you what you use for this purpose, there are many, many different options.